# Dictionary with type as value

Tags: c#, types, dictionary

I need a dictionary that can do this:

```
Dictionary properties = new Dictionary();
properties.Add<PhysicalLogic>(new Projectile(velocity));

// at a later point
PhysicalLogic logic = properties.Get<PhysicalLogic>();
```

I found [this](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shimmy/archive/2011/05/09/dictionary-lt-type-t-gt-use-generic-type-argument-for-keys.aspx) article which has something similar to what I want, but not quite.

Unity3D does it with their `GetComponent<>()` method, so it should be possible:
http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html
(Click the "JavaScript" dropdown to see the C# version)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no built-in class that does this.

You can write one yourself by wrapping a `Dictionary<Type, object>` and casting the result in `Get<T>()`:

```
public class TypedDictionary {
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, object> dict = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    public void Add<T>(T item) {
        dict.Add(typeof(T), item);
    }

    public T Get<T>() { return (T) dict[typeof(T)]; }
}
```

Note that this will add items based on their compile-time type, and that you will not be able to resolve using anything other than the exact type (as opposed to base types or variantly convertible types).

If you want to overcome those limitations, consider using a full IoC system like Autofac, which does all that and more.

A dictionary cannot help there, because type convertibility is not an equivalence relation.
For example, both `string` and `int` should count as `object`, but those two types do not equal each-other.

Comment: That works great. Is there anyway I can get something like this to work with it though? properties.Add<someVar.GetType()>(someVar);

Answer (score 2):

Strictly based on your example (ie one type can only have one entry) you can achieve this two way:

**Custom Dictionary**

```
public class TypedDictionary : Dictionary<Type, object>
{
    public void Add<T>(T value)
    {
        var type = typeof (T);

        if (ContainsKey(type))
            this[type] = value;
        else
            Add(type, value);
    }

    public T Get<T>()
    {
        // Will throw KeyNotFoundException
        return (T) this[typeof (T)];
    }

    public bool TryGetValue<T>(out T value)
    {
        var type = typeof (T);
        object intermediateResult;

        if (TryGetValue(type, out intermediateResult))
        {
            value = (T) intermediateResult;
            return true;
        }

        value = default(T);
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Extension Method**

```
public static class TypedDictionaryExtension
{
    public static void Add<T>(this Dictionary<Type, object> dictionary, T value)
    {
        var type = typeof (T);

        if (dictionary.ContainsKey(type))
            dictionary[type] = value;
        else
            dictionary.Add(type, value);
    }

    public static T Get<T>(this Dictionary<Type, object> dictionary)
    {
        // Will throw KeyNotFoundException
        return (T) dictionary[typeof (T)];
    }

    public static bool TryGetValue<T>(this Dictionary<Type, object> dictionary, out T value)
    {
        var type = typeof (T);
        object intermediateResult;

        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(type, out intermediateResult))
        {
            value = (T) intermediateResult;
            return true;
        }

        value = default(T);
        return false;
    }
}
```

First method is more explicit where as the other one only require a specific type of dictionary.